# Facebook fql query for getting all the liked object of user

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Iam using fql query for getting all the liked object of a current user.When i run this query

```
SELECT user_id, object_id, post_id, object_type FROM like where user_id='".$user_id."'
```

Iam getting some results.How i can link to the corresponding object.ie if it is a photo i want to see the photo or it is a comment i want to see that.The object type is same for all the results,it is profile.Is it possible to do this

Comment: This is new.  This query only used to return likes of pages.  Good find.  I notice the "list" type is really a like of a "link".

Answer (score 0):

From the `object_type` ....

> The type of the liked object. One of: photo, album, event, group, note, link, video, application, status, check-in, review, comment, post

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

You will have to write a few if statements to then retrieve the data from the appropriate table. Facebook does not provide an automated way of doing this.

Comment: The object type is same for all the result. It is profile even if i liked a comment or a photo or a video

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
SELECT user_id, object_id, post_id, object_type FROM like where user_id='".$user_id."'
```

[Check out the API doc's](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)